# winapi: get callback when thread ends

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I have some c++ library code that creates some book-keeping data per thread that accesses it (based on thread-id). I would like to cleanup that data when a thread ends. Is there a way (if not portable, then using win-api) to get notified when a thread ends?

// simplified example:

```
std::mutex mutex_;
std::unordered_map<std::thread::id, int> thread_accesses_;

void LibFunction() {
  std::thread::id thread_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
  mutex_.lock();
  std::unordered_map<std::thread::id, int>::const_iterator it = thread_accesses_.find(thread_id);
  if(it == thread_accesses_.end()) {
    thread_accesses_[thread_id] = 0;
  } else {
    thread_accesses_[thread_id]++;
  }
  mutex_.unlock();
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221002/discussion-on-question-by-user1282931-winapi-get-callback-when-thread-ends).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread-local storage is both C++ standard way and platform way.

C++ has `thread_local` keyword to declare thread-local variable. Then destructor of that variable is called for each thread for which it was constructed. Thread local variable is constructed for at least all threads that access the variable, and possibly for other threads.

Windows has thread-local storage as system mechanism. `thread_local` is implemented via this mechanism.

It is possible to have thread exit callbacks in Windows by other means:

- having thread-local data and TLS callbacks in module by other means
- Using DllMain callbacks
- Passing `FlsCallback` in `FlsAlloc`, fiber local storage is something superior to thread local storage, and in absence of fibers it behaves exactly like thread local storage

If cannot use `thread_local`, but want something simple and portable, consider also `boost::thread_specific_ptr`.